# Increasing argument name in a for-loop

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I was just wondering if there is a way to call increment argument in for loop. For example,

```
public void increment(int increment1, int increment2, int increment3)
{

    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
      increment(i) = 1;

}
```

Like that, i wanted to use argument name which have increment numbers to call in for loop.

Thank you :)

Comment: Java is pass-by-value, so assigning something *to* a parameter will likely not have the effect you intended. As for accessing one-of-many values using an integer *index* value, use an **array**. See [The Java™ Tutorials - Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: In addition, for an easy way to accept multiple arguments as an array, use **varargs**. See [The Java™ Tutorials - Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Individual parameters aren't iterable; you'd need a collection for that.
Try changing it to an array instead:

```
public void increment(int increment1, int increment2, int increment3)
{
    int[] array = {increment1, increment2, increment3};

    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
      array[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

or

```
public void increment(int[] increment)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < increment.length; i++){
      increment[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

or

```
public void increment(int... increment)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < increment.length; i++){
      increment[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you directly adress it:

```
increment1 = 1;
increment2 = 1;
increment3 = 1;
```

I see no reason to do this though. Parameters are for the method's use. If you just going change all the values at the beginning of the method, you may as well exclude the parameters.

Comment: Why are you seemingly calling `array` like it's a method? Why would assign a value to the arguments anyway? What are you going to accomplish?